# How to pick specific date from a field of type timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm trying to create a query that would bring the tablets sold on a particular date in oracle. the field data type is timestamp.

Here's the query

```sql
SELECT 
  Order_detail.order_detail_id,
  product_name AS product,
  Product_categ_type.product_categ_type AS category,
  Order_line.qty AS qty,
  order_date
FROM Product, Order_detail, Order_line, Product_categ_type
WHERE Order_detail.order_detail_id = Order_line.order_detail_id
  AND Product.product_id = Order_line.product_id
  AND Product.product_categ_type_id = 3
  AND Product_categ_type.product_categ_type LIKE 'TB%'
  AND order_date = TO_DATE('2022-12-02' ,'yyyy,mm,dd')
```

The query works but it is not returning any data and I think the problem is in how I'm picking the date

```
-- INSERT INTO PRODUCT TABLE
INSERT INTO Product (product_id,product_categ_type_id,product_name,price,stock_qty) VALUES (174,1,'iWatch',454,183);

INSERT INTO Product (product_id,product_categ_type_id,product_name,price,stock_qty) VALUES (194,3,'Samsung Galaxy Tab',398,114);

INSERT INTO Product (product_id,product_categ_type_id,product_name,price,stock_qty) VALUES (139,1,'Fitness Tracker',312,122);

INSERT INTO Product (product_id,product_categ_type_id,product_name,price,stock_qty) VALUES (150,3,'iPad',366,189);

-- INSERT INTO PRODUCT CATEGORY TABLE

INSERT INTO Product_categ_type (product_categ_type_id,product_categ_type) VALUES (1,'AC');
INSERT INTO Product_categ_type (product_categ_type_id,product_categ_type) VALUES (2,'SP');
INSERT INTO Product_categ_type (product_categ_type_id,product_categ_type) VALUES (3,'TB');

-- INSERT INTO Order detail

INSERT INTO Order_detail (order_detail_id,product_id,customer_id,emp_id) VALUES (144,150,196,113);
INSERT INTO Order_detail (order_detail_id,product_id,customer_id,emp_id) VALUES (183,139,140,197);
INSERT INTO Order_detail (order_detail_id,product_id,customer_id,emp_id) VALUES (172,194,185,113);

-- INSERT INTO Order line

INSERT INTO Order_line (product_id,order_detail_id,qty) VALUES (150,144,1);
INSERT INTO Order_line (product_id,order_detail_id,qty) VALUES (139,183,5);
INSERT INTO Order_line (product_id,order_detail_id,qty) VALUES (194,172,1);
```

Comment: You need to match the way the date is spelled in the string. Also make sure to truncate the date you are trying to match. Try `AND TRUNC(order_date) = TO_DATE('2022-12-02' ,'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: "the field data type is timestamp."  Which field?  And I see you have a filter for `order_date = TO_DATE('2022-12-02' ,'yyyy,mm,dd')`, but there is no order_date in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 24-hour range:

```sql
AND order_date >= DATE '2022-12-02'
AND order_date <  DATE '2022-12-03'
```

Alternatively, you could use `TRUNC` to truncate the column back to midnight of the same day so that you do not need to worry about the time component:

```sql
AND TRUNC(order_date) = DATE '2022-12-02'
```

However, in that case, Oracle would not be able to use any index on the `order_date` column and would need to use a function-based index on `TRUNC(order_date)` so it is often better to use ranges.